# How to execute a file within a subdirectory

Tags: c#, .net

So I have a small setup file that needs to install a few run-time files. The files are located within sub directories of the root of the drive. The drive letter will be different on every customers machine, so I was trying this and several other methods to no avail.

```
            // File is being ran from D:\ "eg: D:\setup.exe"
            // All my runtimes are in the Tools\Runtime direcorties
            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string ext = "/q /norestart";
            string location = "\\Tools\\Runtimes\\Net\\";
            string step1 = "dotnetfx35.exe";
            var process = Process.Start(path + location + step1 + ext);
            process.WaitForExit();
```

As you pros and more experienced programmers know, for some reason... It doesn't work
I keep getting file not found.

Comment: There might be other issues, but I think you want a different overload of Process.Start since the first argument is (confusingly) just the file name. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Set full path to "Tools".For example `Process.Start("C:\\Tools\\Runtimes\\Net\\" + step1 + ext)`. GetCurrentDirectory() can return differnt directories